# Is using the @ (at sign) an acceptible replacement for the word "at" for screen readers?

Tags: accessibility, screen-reader

When thinking foremost about accessibility, is there any issue in replacing the word "at" with the @ (at sign)?

Example 1: "meet me @ 2pm" vs. "meet me at 2pm"

Example 2: "Topic@Company" vs. "Topic @ Company" vs. "Topic at Company"

Does this confuse screen readers or users—perhaps make them think an email address is coming? I couldn't find any resources on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

This *sort of* fits into a few different WCAG checkpoints, but you might have to stretch your interpretation of the guidelines a bit.

- [3.1.3 Unusual Words](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#unusual-words) - You might not consider the @ sign an "unusual word" (or even a "word" at all)
- [3.1.4 Abbreviations](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#abbreviations) - You might not consider the @ sign an abbreviation, but it kind of is for the word "at".
- [3.1.5 Reading Level](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#reading-level) - The reading level to understand that @ means "at" might fall into the category of "advanced" reading level.
- [3.1.6 Pronunciation](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#pronunciation) - This is usually applied to real words and not symbols but the guideline doesn't specifically say that.

Most screen readers will say "at" but a screen reader user is just one persona.  You have to consider people with reading disabilities too.  Is it common for most everyone to associate @ with "at"?  That would require a bit of research.

Unless there's a really good reason to use @, I would use "at" instead.

Comment: My initial thought was to look into the abbreviations checkpoint, but I think the reading level is an interesting one I had not considered.

Comment: Excellent answer. Regarding unusual words and reading level, I think the at-symbol may have been quite obcure in the past, but it's far more widely understood in the era of email. Nonetheless, it may be unfamiliar to users with low _computer_ literacy.

Comment: Regarding abbreviations, I'd say the @ symbol is certainly an abbreviation for "at". It's in the same league as the ampersand (&), which is a stylized ligature of "Et" (meaning "and").

Comment: Thanks @andrew. The use of @ in emails is certainly something to consider.

Answer (score -1):

Ultimately this will depend on the capabilities of the screen reader. But I think for safe measure you should use 'at'. It's only 2 characters.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm trying to build a case for allowing or denying a request to use the @ symbol as part of a name in text on a website, so I'm looking for some data or expertise to decide one way or another.